# Similarity of matrices and its square root over $\mathbb Z$

Tags: matrix-analysis, matrix-congruences

I already ask this but now its "for all"

Prove or disprove:

$A \in M(3,\mathbb{Z})$ has a square root with integer entries if and only if  $XAX^{-1} \in M(3,\mathbb{Z})$ has a square root with integer entries, for all invertible $X \in M(3,\mathbb{R})$

Answer (score 0):

Consider the matrices $$A=\begin{pmatrix} 
0 & 0 & 9 \\
9 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 9 & 0 \\ 
\end{pmatrix}
\quad$$

and

$$B=\begin{pmatrix} 
0 & 3 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 3 \\
3 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}
\quad$$

Observe that $A,B \in \Bbb M_3 (\Bbb Z)$ with $A=B^2.$ So $A$ has a square root with integer entries.

Let us consider the matrix

$$X=\begin{pmatrix} 
\frac 1 3 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 3 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}
\quad$$

Then you will easily find that

$$XAX^{-1} = 
\begin{pmatrix} 
0 & 0 & 3 \\
81 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 3 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}
\quad$$

Then $XAX^{-1}$ is a matrix with integer entries. But there doesn't exist any $C \in \Bbb M(3,\Bbb Z)$ such that $XAX^{-1} = C^2.$

For a proof of the above assertion see this [link.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3118014/543867)

Comment: Ummmm. XAX^-1 must be in M(3,Z) at the first place.  Your example does not admits integer entries.